# How to change value of a cell after reloading in objective c?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

is there any way to change value of a cell after it is loaded? actually i am having one textfield in the table and after inserting the value of the same,i need to do some numeric operations on the textfield value and the value calculater need to display on the lable that in in the next cell.

So how can i get the same result?any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the label is created runtime?

Comment: I couldn't understand where is your problem. Do you need to update the text of a UITextField and that textfield is inside a cell that you don't have a reference to?

Comment: yes it is created at run time. In the cellForRowAtIndexPath method i m passing value in textfield which should be reflected in the label which is in the next cell.The textfield value should remain as it is,and the label value should be changes from 0 to something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to update a cell in a `UITableView`.

1) Call the table view method `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`. This will trigger a call to the delegate method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. If you have a data source that you are updating this would be a good way to update a cell.

```
NSIndexPath *indexPathOfUpdatedCell = ...
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPathOfUpdatedCell] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

2) It is also possible to update the cell directly. You can use `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

```
NSIndexPath *indexPathOfUpdatedCell = ...
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPathOfUpdatedCell];
cell.textLabel.text = @"new value";
```

To create an index path for a specific row and section it is possible to use `indexPathForRow:inSection`.

```
NSUInteger row = ...
NSUInteger section = ...
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
```

Comment: Thank you for the help,but can u tell me how can i pass the row index in the NSIndexPath *indexPathOfUpdatedCell. I tried indexAtPosition but i m not getting specific format.

Comment: Thank u so much Robert for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

For what you are trying to do, your best bet is to make your view controller a `<UITextFieldDelegate>`, set your cell's text field delegate to self, and then implement the textFieldDidEndEditing: delegate method.

Change your interface file to adopt the protocol

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Then set the view controller as the delegate of your relevant UITextField(s)...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ...
    yourCustomCell.yourTextField.delegate = self
}
```

And finally implement

```
- (void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField.
```

This method will get called everytime the user finishes editing your UITextField, and as it passes a reference to it you can access it's values, do any validation you may need and assign it back to the textfield.